# MYSQL Update table trigger

Tags: mysql, eventtrigger, triggers

This is just a quick question and I apologize if it's simple but I haven't been able to find any good examples, because I am sure it isn't that hard, I am just not sure on the syntax.

I need to update a status attribute in one table 'Airplane' when someone inserts the airplane in a table called servicing, they set a status too it, say 'inactive' I need that to correspond to the other table. I feel this should be easy but have been struggling with it for a while now.

Thank you in advance.

Here is the airplane table

```
Create Table Airplane(
    Name    Char(25)    NOT NULL,
    aID     Int NOT NULL Primary Key,
    aCount  Int,
    status  Char(8) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Active',
    cost    double Default 0.0
);
```

Here is the servicing table, they are subject to change, was just focused on this trigger for all intensive purposes.

```
Create table Servicing( 
 TicketNumber Int  NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT Primary Key,
 Mechanic  Char(50) NOT NULL,
 Problem   Char(25) NOT NULL,
 Airplane  Char(25) NOT NULL,
 TimeComplete CHAR(25) NOT NULL,
 Servicing  Char(25) NOT NULL,
 Status   Char(25) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Inactive');
```

Here is the trigger but seem to be running into issues.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER Airplane_status_update 
AFTER INSERT ON Servicing
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
UPDATE Airplane status 
   SET status = new.status
 WHERE name = new.airplane;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: This sounds like application logic. Why are you doing it in your database? Triggers can be serious trouble.

Comment: I agree with you 100% i know how to do intermediate mysql and this is for a mysql class to which my teacher thinks he knows all when he knows very little, I have most of this handled by software overlay when creating programs using databases, it gets frustrating trust me.

Comment: At least you're going into this with your eyes open. When all you have is a hammer, everything's a nail, right? Some DBA-types are especially like this, where no stored procedure is too huge. Hope you can survive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for something like this

```sql
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER airplane_status_update 
AFTER INSERT ON servicing
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
UPDATE airplane 
   SET status = NEW.status
 WHERE airplane_id = NEW.airplane_id;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

*You obviously need to tweak an UPDATE statement specifying correct field names since you didn't post DDL for servicing and airplane tables*

Comment: I apologize for that, what you gave me looked like it should have fit my small example quickly, if you can look at it and see the small issue before I realize it I'd appreciate it too.

Comment: I got it to work thank you though, safe mode with mysqlwork bench was the only issue. Thank youbtw